# Can I run Jasmine + Protractor tests in a browser?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I am preparing a suite of E2E tests using protractor and Jasmine. Currently I'm running these from the command line using Node. In the past I've used Jasmine tests with the SpecRunner.html setup, which shows the results in the browser as they are run, allows you to select individual tests or sub-suites of tests to run, etc.

Has anyone set up Jasmine + Protractor tests in that way - output going into one browser window, while tests run in another browser window?

Alternatively, is there a Jasmine reporter that will provide a similar output format even if I still have to run the tests from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For jasmine2, look into [`jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter) package.

For jasmine1:

I've used [`protractor-html-screenshot-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter) package that generates nice test reports including screenshots:

- initialize a `baseDirectory` inside the `onPrepare` function:

  ```
  onPrepare: function() {
        // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screnshots`:
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
           baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
        }));
     }
  ```
- and observe a nicely HTML formatted test results:

[image]

Hope this is what you were asking about.

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to use this configuration with protractor, rather than grunt, as the runner.

Comment: This did not work for me, because I'm using jasmine2, I used [protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter) instead.

Comment: @areve okay, makes sense, added a note to the answer. Thanks!